# Calculate the number of products responsible for 50% of my sales

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a shop that sells products in different countries.

I end up with a sales table like this ( with much more month)

| Month | Country | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | UK | Tomato | 10 |
| 01-2022 | UK | Banana | 4 |
| 01-2022 | UK | Garlic | 1 |
| 01-2022 | FR | Tomato | 1 |
| 01-2022 | FR | Banana | 2 |
| 01-2022 | FR | Garlic | 1 |

I would like to know the number of products responsible for 50% of the sales per month and country. Something like this.

| Month | Country | Nb products accountable for 50% sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | UK | 1 |
| 02-2022 | UK | 3 |
| 03-2022 | UK | 2 |
| 01-2022 | FR | 1 |
| 02-2022 | FR | 4 |
| 03-2022 | FR | 3 |

The objective is to have the percentage of my catalogue responsible for the majority of sales. Exemple: 10% of my catalogue represents 50% of sales.

I have tried to solve the problem with multiple window functions and I have already searched the open topics without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution tweaking windows functions.

```js
,t1 AS (
SELECT 
*
,SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY country_group, order_date ORDER BY sales DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING) AS running_total 
,0.5*SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY country_group, order_date) AS total_sales_x_50perc
FROM t0
ORDER BY 1
)


SELECT 
order_date
,country_group
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN running_total <= total_sales_x_50perc THEN product ELSE NULL END) AS nb_products
,COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS total_nb_products
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN running_total <= total_sales_x_50perc THEN product ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(DISTINCT products) AS perc
FROM t1
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```